# Optimize mysql query by not using/inquiring same table twice

Tags: mysql, database

Thanks for your kind words and wisdom in helping me optimize the following query as I would like to use the "answers" table only once. As well, if there is any explanation accompanying it, I would be delighted.

---

```
SELECT
score.user_id,
name_email.NAME,
score.question_id,
TRUNCATE(GREATEST(0, SUM(answers.is_correct / IF(answers.is_correct = 1, possible_answers.good_answers, possible_answers.wrong_answers))) ,2) AS score
FROM score

INNER JOIN (
SELECT
id,
email,
CONCAT(users.f_name, " ", users.l_name) as NAME
FROM
users
)AS name_email

INNER JOIN answers

INNER JOIN (
SELECT
answers.question_id,
count(*) AS total_answers,
SUM(IF(is_correct = 1, 1, 0)) AS good_answers,
SUM(IF(is_correct = -1, 1, 0)) AS wrong_answers
FROM answers
GROUP BY answers.question_id
) AS possible_answers

WHERE score.answer_id = answers.id
AND possible_answers.question_id = score.question_id
AND score.user_id = name_email.id
-- AND score.user_id = 2
-- AND score.question_id = 1007
GROUP BY score.question_id, score.user_id
ORDER BY score.user_id, score.question_id
;
```

---

Comment: Mind building a schema for testing? http://sqlfiddle.com/ Also, I only see one select from answers table...

Comment: I would like not to employ answers twice. Once in the join and second in the select just below.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/66fd3c

Comment: You included schema, can you now include a little data to play with?

Comment: my bad: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7ceb7/1

Comment: I'm not sure what you want is possible. You're query appears to involve getting information about every answer in relation to all possible answers; which will inherently require answers to be compared (i.e. multiple references).

Comment: Uueerdo, is there another way of rewriting this query then? maybe starting from answers instead of score?

Comment: With respect, your goal of *not employing `answers` twice* isn't worthwhile. Recent versions of database servers, including MySQL, have query planner software that knows a lot about how to avoid redundant table access. Very smart teams have spent thousands of programmer years (truly! thousands!) figuring out how to avoid the sorts of redundant access that come from self-join operations.  If you want to improve performance, put `ON` clauses in your joins and consider judiciously adding indexes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note all queries (including your original) are improved by adding a composite index on the scores table, like so:

```
ALTER TABLE `score` ADD INDEX `score_comp_uaq` (`user_id`, `answer_id`, `question_id`);
```

Your final score formula refers to answers in 2 different contexts:

1. the possible answers, and
2. the actual answers

So, one way to avoid using the answers table twice is to use an outer join so we can access both the possible and the actual in one pass. However in this approach there is a problem of knowing which questions a user has attempted so while it reduces the passes over the answers table it requires 2 passes of the scores table.

```
SELECT
      d.user_id
    , CONCAT(users.f_name, " ", users.l_name) as NAME
    , d.question_id
    , d.good_answers
    , d.wrong_answers
    , d.possible_good
    , d.possible_wrong
    , COALESCE((d.good_answers / NULLIF(d.possible_good,0)),0) x
    , COALESCE((d.wrong_answers / NULLIF(d.possible_wrong,0)),0) y
FROM (
      SELECT
              u.user_id
            , a.question_id
            , SUM(case when s.user_id IS NOT NULL AND a.is_correct = 1 then 1 else 0 end) AS good_answers
            , SUM(case when s.user_id IS NOT NULL AND a.is_correct =-1 then 1 else 0 end) AS wrong_answers
            , SUM(case when a.is_correct = 1 then 1.0 else 0.0 end) AS possible_good
            , SUM(case when a.is_correct =-1 then 1.0 else 0.0 end) AS possible_wrong
      from answers a
      INNER join (select distinct user_id, question_id from score) u
                        ON a.question_id = u.question_id
      left join score s ON u.user_id = s.user_id
                        AND a.question_id = s.question_id
                        AND a.id = s.answer_id
      GROUP BY
            u.user_id
          , a.question_id
     ) d
INNER JOIN users ON d.user_id = users.id
;
```

While that may be an option I believe the next query offers a better explain plan:

```
SELECT
      s.user_id
    , CONCAT(users.f_name, " ", users.l_name) as NAME
    , s.question_id
    , s.good_answers
    , s.wrong_answers
    , pa.possible_good
    , pa.possible_wrong
    , COALESCE((s.good_answers / NULLIF(pa.possible_good,0)),0) x
    , COALESCE((s.wrong_answers / NULLIF(pa.possible_wrong,0)),0) y
FROM (
     select
            score.user_id
          , answers.question_id
          , count(*) AS total_answers
          , SUM(IF(is_correct = 1, 1, 0)) AS good_answers
          , SUM(IF(is_correct = -1, 1, 0)) AS wrong_answers
      from score
      INNER JOIN answers ON score.answer_id = answers.id
      GROUP BY
            score.user_id
          , answers.question_id
     ) s
INNER JOIN (
        SELECT
              answers.question_id
            , count(*) AS total_answers
            , SUM(IF(is_correct = 1, 1.0, 0.0)) AS possible_good
            , SUM(IF(is_correct = -1, 1.0, 0.0)) AS possible_wrong
        FROM answers
        GROUP BY answers.question_id
      ) AS pa ON s.question_id = pa.question_id
INNER JOIN users ON s.user_id = users.id
;
```

Notice that I have not attempted to reproduce your final "score" formula. I feel that you may want to amend how you do that after seeing these options, but the columns aliased "x" and "y" should allow you to arrange a final formula.

[**This SQLfiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2522be/1) allows you to inspect both the above and your original.

first query:

```
+----+-------------+-------+--------+------------------------------------------------------+----------------+---------+------------------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table |  type  |                    possible_keys                     |      key       | key_len |       ref        | rows | filtered |                    Extra                     |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+------------------------------------------------------+----------------+---------+------------------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     |       | ALL    |                                                      |                |         |                  |    4 |   100.00 |                                              |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | users | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                              | PRIMARY        |       4 | d.user_id        |    1 |   100.00 |                                              |
|  2 | DERIVED     |       | ALL    |                                                      |                |         |                  |    4 |   100.00 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  2 | DERIVED     | a     | ref    | question_id                                          | question_id    |       4 | u.question_id    |    1 |   100.00 |                                              |
|  2 | DERIVED     | s     | ref    | user_id,answer_choice,question_choice,score_comp_uaq | answer_choice  |       5 | db_9_2522be.a.id |    1 |   100.00 | Using where                                  |
|  3 | DERIVED     | score | index  | score_comp_uaq                                       | score_comp_uaq |      14 |                  |    4 |   100.00 | Using index; Using temporary                 |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+------------------------------------------------------+----------------+---------+------------------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
```

second query:

```
+----+-------------+---------+--------+---------------+----------------+---------+-----------------------------+------+----------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table   | type   | possible_keys | key            | key_len | ref                         | rows | filtered | Extra                                                     |
+----+-------------+---------+--------+---------------+----------------+---------+-----------------------------+------+----------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| 1  | PRIMARY     |         | ALL    |               |                |         |                             | 4    | 100.00   |                                                           |
| 1  | PRIMARY     | users   | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY        | 4       | s.user_id                   | 1    | 100.00   |                                                           |
| 1  | PRIMARY     |         | ref    |               |                | 4       | s.question_id               | 2    | 100.00   |                                                           |
| 3  | DERIVED     | answers | index  | question_id   | question_id    | 4       |                             | 19   | 100.00   |                                                           |
| 2  | DERIVED     | score   | index  | answer_choice | score_comp_uaq | 14      |                             | 4    | 100.00   | Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort |
| 2  | DERIVED     | answers | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY        | 4       | db_9_2522be.score.answer_id | 1    | 100.00   |                                                           |
+----+-------------+---------+--------+---------------+----------------+---------+-----------------------------+------+----------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
```

original query:

```
+----+-------------+---------+--------+------------------------------------------------------+----------------+---------+-------------------------------+------+----------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type |  table  |  type  |                    possible_keys                     |      key       | key_len |              ref              | rows | filtered |                           Extra                           |
+----+-------------+---------+--------+------------------------------------------------------+----------------+---------+-------------------------------+------+----------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | score   | index  | user_id,answer_choice,question_choice,score_comp_uaq | score_comp_uaq |      14 |                               |    4 |   100.00 | Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | answers | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                              | PRIMARY        |       4 | db_9_2522be.score.answer_id   |    1 |   100.00 |                                                           |
|  1 | PRIMARY     |         | ref    |                                                      |                |       4 | db_9_2522be.score.user_id     |    2 |   100.00 |                                                           |
|  1 | PRIMARY     |         | ref    |                                                      |                |       4 | db_9_2522be.score.question_id |    2 |   100.00 |                                                           |
|  3 | DERIVED     | answers | index  | question_id                                          | question_id    |       4 |                               |   19 |   100.00 |                                                           |
|  2 | DERIVED     | users   | ALL    |                                                      |                |         |                               |    9 |   100.00 |                                                           |
+----+-------------+---------+--------+------------------------------------------------------+----------------+---------+-------------------------------+------+----------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: This does gives me perspective! Thank you for your time guys!